# Not able access data in "it" rails rspec test class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

When we are trying to execute the below code we are not able access data `newAccount` and `also not able to search date in active records` in `it` method

**Code Extract:**

```
describe "search with name" do
                before :each do
                    newAccount = Account.new
                    newAccount.firstname = "涯噘暮"
                    newAccount.id = "405"
                    newAccount.save
                    data  = Account.execute_sql(['Select * from account where sfid= ? ','1'])
                    puts "Debug : #{data.to_json}"
                    newAccount = Account.new
                    newAccount.firstname = "涯 噘 暮"
                    newAccount.id = "2"
                    newAccount.save
                end
                it "should return direct matches during search" do
                    puts "#{newAccount}"
                    puts "#{Account.find_by_id(405)}"
                end
end
```

**Details of gem lib:** These are the libraries that we are using for testing.

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
gem 'faker'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'guard-rspec'
gem 'launchy'
gem 'simplecov', :require => false
gem 'resque_spec'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors here:

1. Variable names in Ruby are case-sensitive, so `newaccount` is different from `newAccount`, use one of them, preferably [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) recommends snake case (`new_account`)
2. `newAccount` in `before(:each)` is not visible in any `it` block. Consider them as different methods of one object, this way each method has its own local variables, that are invisible for other variables. The solution is to use instance variables, that can be shared inside different methods of one object.

This code should work:

```
describe "search with name" do
    before :each do
        @newAccount = Account.new
        @newAccount.firstname = "涯噘暮"
        @newAccount.id = "405"
        @newAccount.save
        data  = Account.execute_sql(['Select * from account where sfid= ? ','1'])
        puts "Debug : #{data.to_json}"
        @newAccount = Account.new
        @newAccount.firstname = "涯 噘 暮"
        @newAccount.id = "2"
        @newAccount.save
    end
    it "should return direct matches during search" do
        puts "#{@newAccount}"
        puts "#{Account.find_by_id(405)}"
    end
end
```

You need to check if your account is really saved. You can

1. Add `p @newAccount.errors.full_messages` after `@newAccount.save` to see if there are any validation errors preventing your model to be saved.
2. Use `@newAccount.save!` instead of `@newAccount.save` (note the `!` character). This will throw an exception if your save was unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks for response @ alexey shein. 

1. newaccount was typo, it was my mistake :)
2. I am also not able access inserted account added using this Account.find_by_id(405).

Comment: @AjayGupta, if I'm not mistaken, `.find_by_id` is deprecated. I think the correct way is `.find_by(id: id)`. Also, just `.find` should do the trick.

Comment: I have tried but still not working, please suggest something